# contact import/export

Tags: ios

I've got Verizon service with 3 devices, I've got an iTunes account. 2 of the devices are mine. I must keep the child on my iTunes account for 'find the iphone' app.
Is there a way to share my contact list from device to device within my account without it being accessed by the child?

Comment: Why 'must' you use the same account? Use [Family Sharing](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201060)  instead.

Answer (score 2):

[Family Sharing](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201060), as suggested by @Tetsujin, is a perfect option for a child device.
It allows you to:

- Share purchases
- Set limits to purchases made by the child, or let they ask for purchases and approve remotely
- Share Apple Music or music purchased from Apple
- Share and see other family member's location on Messages or Find My Friends
- Use Find My iPhone for all devices
- Activate [Restrictions](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201304) on iOS and Parental control on macOS
- Share calendars and Photos Albums

And it lets you fully sync your own data between your devices, because the accounts are independent.

Comment: I use Family Sharing for myself and my two kids. It's a wonderful way to keep things separate, but still integrated in a way. This really is a great suggestion.